# Generate code with specific type element on Lombok

Tags: java, annotations, code-injection, lombok

I want to add a costume annotation on `lombok` to Generate another variable  from one variable.

I want to create an `annotation` with a `Lombok` This annotation `@selectOne` :

```
   @selectOne
    Private String client;
```

Now I want to add automatically  variable who inject this code :

```
Private String client;
List <String> listClient;
List <String> selectClient;
```

It don't work when I add a type Element  type variable to a List but it work when it like this :

```
Private String client;
List  listClient;
List selectClient;
```

On lombok i used this code to generate variables:

```
JavacNode node;
JCExpression    typeList =chainDots(node, "java", "util", "List");
this variable typeList type java.util.List
```

and I want that `typeList` be a `java.util.List<String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found this solution

```
JCExpression testDeclarList =maker.TypeApply(chainDotsString(fieldNode, "java.util.List"), List.<JCExpression>of(genJavaLangTypeRef(fieldNode, "String")));
```